# What is the song in 'Mars Attacks!' that killed the Martians?

Tags: soundtrack, mars-attacks

The evil Martians were killed by a song near the end of the `Mars Attack!` movie. What is the title of the song? A youtube link will be helpful.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSbigjiKLoU here the song, no idea what it is though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Attacks!):

> Richie discovers that the Martians' heads explode when they hear **Slim Whitman's "Indian Love Call."** He and Florence drive around town, using the song to kill Martians. The military thereafter broadcast the song around the globe, killing most of the Martians and their leader and causing the few remaining survivors to either flee from Earth or surrender.

Comment: The [script](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~ina22/splaylib/Screenplay-Mars_Attacks.pdf) concurs :-)

Comment: After Richie picks up his Grandma, there is another similar song that plays during the pickup scenes for 1-2 seconds but most of the scenes do have the Slim Whitman's song